# Not able to create the object by new if new operator is overloaded and constructor is private

Tags: c++

Can any body explain why i am not able to create the object using new if it is overloaded and constructor is private.

```
class A
{
      A();
      A(A const &obj);
      A& operator =(A const &obj);

public:
     void * operator new(Size_t size)
     {
         void * p = malloc (size);
         return  p ;
     }
};

int main ()
{
    A * p = new A() /*gives compile time error, saying constructor
        is private.But cant we access private function from class
        public function . as operator new is public function of class.*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's unclear? The constructor is private, so you cannot access it.

Comment: Are you sure your class should have a public function `main`? Please always make sure your code is properly formattes as well: No over-long lines and all code formatted as code.

Comment: Your `operator new` is not accessing the constructor at all (just read the code). You are trying to use it from outside your class, so the error is correct. BTW, I've added a `}` I think you were missing by mistake.

Comment: I can understand the question. He thinks that, because the new operator is in the class, it should be able to access the constructor. The main function being in the class is probably a typo.

Comment: When you call new, that is actually 1) a call to the allocator, 2) a call to the constructor, 3) If 2 throws, a call to the deallocator.

Comment: Yes Neil , i understood it correctly . it was a typo .But now u can look at the code and u will understand my concern very well.Its very simple , why private constructor is not accessible from overloaded (new)member function of class.Thats what my question is.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve with this code. Do you want to allow construction *only using the new-expression*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you are conflating a *new-expression* with `operator new`.

An `operator new` is an **allocation function**, with a confusing name. It should better have been called `_alloc` or some such.

A *new-expression*

- calls the allocation function, passing any specified arguments.
- if that succeeds, calls the class constuctor with specified arguments.
  *Here the relevant constructor must be accessible.*
- if that fails, cleans up by deallocating memory (in the case where the allocation function has user defined arguments, a corresponding user defined deallocation function is called with the originally specified custom allocation function arguments).

In short, a *new-expression* guarantees that if you have fulfilled your obligations, then you will either have an initialized object at hand, or an exception with no memory leak.

One way to not fulfill your obligations is to defined a custom allocation function with no custom deallocation function. Then in the last bullet point above you get no cleanup, and hence a memory leak. But other than that, a *new-expression* is almost like a database transaction, it guarantees all-or-nothing.

Comment: Yes agreed. But regards to your point number 2. If my new operator function is member function of class (It is overloaded and it is not global public in our case) so after allocation of the memory our PRIVATE CONSTRUCTOR should be accessible right? as it also a member function of the class. Then what exactly here is going on ?why the private constructor is not accessible in overloaded new ?

Comment: Because it is not called *inside of* your `operator new`. Imagine the *new-expression* being a composition of the three steps mentioned in the answer. Then calling the `operator new` and calling your constructor are two *different things*. The first succeeds, but the second can't be done due to missing access permissions. Remember, the constructor is still being called by the *outer* code, **not** `operator new`!

Comment: Yeah leemes , thanks your ans is quite satisfactory. i was thinking that it is called in operator new .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is called *after* operator new. As you can see, in `operator new` you are only using `malloc` to allocate raw memory. Afterwards, default constructor is called to initialize class members. So `new A()` calls both, `operator new` and constructor, constructor is private, so you cannot access it, and thus compiler won't allow it.

Comment: But The thing is My new operator is a public member function of class and constructor is a private member function so within public member function we can access private member function .So why this is not true in this case when i use statement A * p =new A();

Comment: You do *not* call the constructor in the `operator new`. It is called in `main`, which is not allowed due to your access permissions.

Comment: @anil It is not operator new who calls constructor. The constructor is called from `main` function. `operator new` finishes its job, and if everything is ok, constructor is called, from place where `new A()` was used. That means, constructor is not called from within `operator new`, but from `main`, which is not internal function of `A` class. Try to call `new A()` inside some other member function - that way it should work.